# issues with the ggplot in R for plotting heat map data latest R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code to plot a square matrix (heat map) that I could plot in my previous laptop with R but now with a new laptop and latest R package I keep getting an error.

my matrix is:

```
matrix_values <- c(0.16, -0.4, -0.7, -0.1, -0.8, -0.1, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.09,
0.7, -0.1, 0.85, -1.9, -0.8, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.65, -1.37, -2.22, 1.53,
0.79, 0.72, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.2, -.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.6, 0.9, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.8,
-1.31, 0.57, -1.55, -1.34, 0.7, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.73, 0.4, 0.62, 0.2,
1.01, -0.52, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.49, 1.99, 1.11, -0.62, -3.22, -0.02, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.33, -0.88, -0.95, 0.03, -0.88, -0.38, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.28, 2.24,
1.04, 0.08, 0, 0.54, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.87, 0.72, -0.09, -0.29, -1.92, -0.91, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.41, 1.82, 2.34, 2.56, 1.12, 0.86, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.57,
0.83, -0.63, -1.69, -0.75, 0.59, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.13, 2.74, 3.47, 1.96,
1.52, 0.99, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.68, 2.09, 1.87, 0.77, 0.69, -0.31, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.2, -0.23, -0.44, -1.4, -1.91, -0.98, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.07, 0.93,
0.25, -1.26, 0.05, 0.49, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.61, -0.22, -1.36, -1.36, -1.16,
-0.91, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.67, -0.39, -0.67, -1.12, -0.94, 0.24, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,
0.91, -1.18, 1.27, -1.16, -0.38, -0.35, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.54, 0.94, 0.17,
-0.92, -1, -0.18, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.63, 1.19, -0.12, -2.02, -1.81, 0.98, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.62, 1.69, 1.96, -0.48, -0.31, -0.54, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.3,
1.04, 1.54, -0.63, 0.18, 0.74, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.87, 0.32, -0.79, -0.75,
-0.71, -0.75, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.36, -0.52, 0.25, -0.47, -0.1, 0.29, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.18, 1.24, -0.56, -1.01, -1.05, -1.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.8, -0.35,
1.76, -0.9, 0.18, 0.14, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.81, -0.07, -0.8, -0.72, -0.16,
0.01, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.71, -0.29, 1.7, 0.88, 0.97, 0.81, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.98,
0.7, 1.99, 0.3, 0.2, -0.03, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -0.99, -0.08, 1.26, 0.19,
0.18, 0.81, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.8, 0.03, 0.34, -1.05, -0.34, 0.08, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.87, 1.19, 1.03, 0.38, 0.09, 0.73, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.48, 1.25,
-0.15, -2.09, -1.05, 0.27, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.36, 1.05, 0.26, 0.41, 0.09,
0.18, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.61, 0.97, 0.84, -0.55, -0.39, 0.04, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)


cor_matrix1 <- matrix(matrix_values, ncol = 37, nrow = 37)
item_names1 <- c('IC 26', 'IC 33', 'IC 38', 'IC 42', 'IC 44','IC 8','IC 15', 'IC 16', 'IC 18','IC 19','IC 25','IC 27','IC 14', 'IC 24','IC 11', 'IC 17', 'IC 20'    ,'IC 23','IC 28','IC 30', 'IC 34', 'IC 35', 'IC 37','IC 39' ,'IC 49', 'IC 32','IC 36','IC 46','IC 2','IC 22','IC 43','IC 13','IC 21','IC 47','IC 1','IC 3','IC 12')

item_names <- c('IC 26', 'IC 33', 'IC 38', 'IC 42', 'IC 44','IC 8','IC 15', 'IC 16', 'IC 18','IC 19','IC 25','IC 27','IC 14', 'IC 24','IC 11', 'IC 17', 'IC 20' ,'IC 23','IC 28','IC 30', 'IC 34', 'IC 35', 'IC 37','IC 39','IC 49', 'IC 32','IC 36','IC 46','IC 2','IC 22','IC 43','IC 13','IC 21','IC 47','IC 1','IC 3','IC 12')

colnames(cor_matrix1) <- item_names1
rownames(cor_matrix1) <- item_names
dat <- melt(cor_matrix1[-38, ])


r45 <- ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) + 
       geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "black") +
       scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("dark blue", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "red", "dark red"), 
                            limit = c(-3, 4)) +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 6, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"), 
             axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 6, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"), 
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),
             axis.title.y = element_blank(),
             panel.background = element_blank())
```

when I type r45 just a blank windows pops up. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @bdemarest consider running the code, if you edit out the problems! See my answer.

Comment: @setempler, Yes, I can now run the code and produce the same plot you posted in your answer.  @Janede, because `matrix_values` is length 1296, it looks like the matrix should be 36 x 36, not 37 x 37??. Also, in `melt(cor_matrix1[-38, ])`, you are trying to remove the 38th row from a 37-row matrix.

Comment: @bdemarest then consider posting the solution, not editing!

Comment: @bdemarest as I suggested, before hitting the button, run the edited code, and you would have recognised it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with `ggplot`.

It is with defining

- `item_names1` and
- `item_names`

where there are quotes (`'`) missing, check string `IC 17`, for example.

Assuming, `melt` is taken from `reshape2`, the result after fixing the two variables above is:

[image]

---

Edit/Note: After @bdemarest edited out the problems in the question, it might not be visible in the code of the OP any more!